# PrecompiledAssemblyException: Multiple precompiled assemblies with the same name UnityEditor

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, topdown

When I imported an asset to unity then I try to run the game this message appeared :

allowed per platform. Assembly paths: C:/Users/ELEMENT14/MyGameIdea/Library/PackageCache/com.unity.ads@2.0.8/Editor/UnityEditor.Advertisements.dll, Assets/2D Top Down Shooter/2D Top Down Shooter/Library/PackageCache/com.unity.ads@2.0.8/Editor/UnityEditor.Advertisements.dll
UnityEditor.Scripting.ScriptCompilation.EditorBuildRules.CreateTargetAssemblies (System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[T] customScriptAssemblies, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[T] precompiledAssemblies) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/Scripting/ScriptCompilation/EditorBuildRules.cs:251)
UnityEditor.Scripting.ScriptCompilation.EditorCompilation.UpdateCustomTargetAssemblies () (at
C:/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/Scripting/ScriptCompilation/EditorCompilation.cs:636)
UnityEditor.Scripting.ScriptCompilation.EditorCompilation.SetAllCustomScriptAssemblyJsons (System.String[] paths) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/Scripting/ScriptCompilation/EditorCompilation.cs:746)
UnityEditor.Scripting.ScriptCompilation.EditorCompilationInterface.SetAllCustomScriptAssemblyJsons (System.String[] allAssemblyJsons) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/Scripting/ScriptCompilation/EditorCompilationInterface.cs:217)
UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr)

My Unity version is 2018.4.11

Comment: As the error states the asset you imported as a precompiled assembly anmed "UnityEditor" while you already have another one with the same name in your project, either remove the asset or rename the assembly called "UnityEditor" to something else if possible.